# have problems with colorbox and jcrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, jcrop

In the code below, the color box is working and the image showing. When I tried to integrate Jcrop with it, it doesn't.

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="../colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script src="../jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <link href="../jcrop/css/jquery.Jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".example1").colorbox();
        $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
        $('#colorbox .example1').Jcrop();
        });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a href="../jcrop/demos/demo_files/flowers.jpg" class="example1">
            crop
        </a>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please describe, with some level of detail, precisely what you mean by "it doesn't work." A link to an example that demonstrates the problem can be extremely useful as well, either a live link to your site, or a http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the script files to the master / parent page, and this should now work..